# SQL - WHERE (X, Y) IN (A, B)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some kind of blockage currently.

My theoretic query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE X in (a, b, c) AND Y IN (d, e, f)
```

So basically, I want all rows having multiple columns match, meaning:

```
X,     Y  
1,     2  
3,     4  
5,     6  
7,     8,  
9,    10
```

If I want to get all rows where `(X=1, Y=2)` or `(X=5, Y=6)`, so X and Y are correlated, how would I do that?

(MS SQL2005+)

Comment: Is Y always equal to X+1 or is that just a coincidence?

Comment: That is just a coincidence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not something simple like the following?

`WHERE (X = 1 AND Y = 2) OR (X = 5 AND Y = 6) ...`

Or, if you're looking for rows (based on your example) where Y should be X + 1, then:

`WHERE Y = X + 1`

If you have thousands of `OR` clauses like the above, then I would suggest you populate a criterion table ahead of time, and rewrite your query as a join.  Suppose you have such a table `Criteria(X, Y)` then your query becomes much simpler:

```
SELECT Table.*
FROM Table
    INNER JOIN Criteria ON Table.X = Criteria.X AND Table.Y = Criteria.Y
```

Don't forget to add an index / foreign keys as necessary to the new table.

If for some reason you prefer to not create a table ahead of time, you can use a temporary table or table variable and populate it within your procedure.

Comment: Thanks. Does that 'scale' when I have like 1000 of those "OR" clauses, or is there a better way?

Comment: @MichelZ No, but neither does an `IN` clause (let alone _two_ `IN` clauses)

Comment: @MichelZ Actually, if you have good indexing, the criteria table option can scale pretty well: even with 1000000's of those clauses

Comment: The main disadvantage of having 1000's of OR clauses would probably be maintainability.

Comment: I think the temp table is what I was missing, that sounds good.

Comment: @MichelZ No, if you have "like 1000" then use a table-valued parameter and perform a join.

Answer (score 1):

If X and Y are in a table then a JOIN would be cleanest:

```
SELECT * FROM Table  t
INNER JOIN XandY xy 
WHERE tX = xy.X AND t.Y = xy.Y
```

If there not in a table I would *strongly* suggest putting them in one.  `IN` only works with single-value sets and there's no way to line up results using multiple `IN` clauses.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is the thing I was missing. putting the things in a temp table and join them looks reasonable. Thanks!